# reattach to docker container detached because of ssh disconnection

Tags: docker, ssh

I conneceted to my server using ssh and then attach to my container using `docker exec -it my-container bash`. After some minutes my ssh connection got frozen and I lost my container bash session which is running some important process. Is there any way to reattach my previous bash session inside my running container after I connect again to my server using ssh?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

Next time you should

1 - Log into your machine

2 - Start a tmux named session ($ tmux new -s myname )

3 - Run the command inside tmux ($ docker exec -it my-container bash )

4 - When your ssh connection freeze you can go back to the same tmux session ( $ tmux a -t myname )